# TCP client server program using c in embedded board(arm64 arch)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, connection, target

I have TCP client-server c programs downloaded from github. The codes are working fine in host machine(x86). But when I have compiled and run the same programs for arm64 architecture board, client "connection refused" error is coming.

### Test setup & procedure

- Target board & host machine are connected using single Ethernet.
- Static IPs are assigned such that both are in same network.
- Target board & host machine both are able to PING their counterpart.
- Server is running in arm64 target board & client in host machine.

### Output:

Socket successfully created..
connection with the server failed...: Connection refused

### Observation

- When both client and server run in target board, connection is getting established.
  The problem is encountered when TCP server & client are running in two different architectures.

Following are the codes

```
**// Server code
//#include <netdb.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 10500
#define SA struct sockaddr 
//print error message and exit process
void die(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0); // EXIT_FAILURE
}
// Function designed for chat between client and server. 
void func(int sockfd) 
{ 
    char buff[MAX]; 
    int n; 
    // infinite loop for chat 
    for (;;) { 
        bzero(buff, MAX); 
        // read the message from client and copy it in buffer 
        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        // print buffer which contains the client contents 
        printf("From client: %s\t To client : ", buff); 
        bzero(buff, MAX); 
        n = 0; 
        // copy server message in the buffer 
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n') 
            ; 
        // and send that buffer to client 
        write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        // if msg contains "Exit" then server exit and chat ended. 
        if (strncmp("exit", buff, 4) == 0) { 
            printf("Server Exit...\n"); 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
} 
// Driver function 
int main() 
{ 
    int sockfd, connfd;
    unsigned int len; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 
    // socket create and verification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // same as socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
    if (sockfd == -1)
        die("socket creation failed...");  
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
        
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); // memset
    // assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* host-to-network endian */
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); /* for listening */
    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification 
    if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) 
        die("socket bind failed..."); 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 
    // Now server is ready to listen and verification 
    if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0)   // max 5 connections
        die("Listen failed...");
    else
        printf("Server listening for any client..\n"); 
        
    len = sizeof(cli); 
    // Accept the data packet from client and verification 
    connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len); 
    if (connfd < 0)
        die("server acccept failed..."); 
    else
        printf("server acccepted the client connection...\n"); 
    // Function for chatting between client and server 
    func(connfd); 
    // After chatting close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
}**
```

```
//client code
// Write CPP code here 
//#include <netdb.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
//#include <netinet/in.h> 

#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 10500
#define SA struct sockaddr 

void die(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0); // EXIT_FAILURE
}

void func(int sockfd) 
{ 
    char buff[MAX]; 
    int n; 
    for (;;) { 
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        printf("Enter the string for sending to server: "); 
        n = 0; 
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n') 
            ; 
        write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
         
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
        printf("From Server : %s", buff); 
        if ((strncmp(buff, "exit", 4)) == 0) { // if Exit message received from Server
            printf("Client Exit...\n"); 
            break; //chat ended
        } 
    } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int sockfd; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr; 

    // socket create and varification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
    if (sockfd == -1)
        die("socket creation failed..."); 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
        
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); // memset

    // assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); /* for connecting */

    // connect the client socket to server socket 
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0)
        die("connection with the server failed...");
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n"); 

    // function for chat 
    func(sockfd); 

    // close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
}
```

This problem is perplexing. I am requesting to please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Perhaps there's a firewall between your client and server? By the way, the server *is* running on the remote host? And you have modified the client to connect to the remote server host instead of localhost (right now you have hard-coded `127.0.0.1` in the client)?

Comment: In host machine firewall is disabled. "ufw status" this command is giving output "Status: inactive". Target board and host machine are connected with a single Ethernet cable . So they are not far apart physically.  And "127.0.0.1" is overwritten by   htonl(INADDR_ANY)

Comment: What about non-local firewalls? Are the client and server hosts on the same network? What about the other possible issued pointed out in my previous comment?

Comment: They both are in same network. PING command is working.

Comment: Then tell us: Is the server *running* on the remote host? And is the client trying to connect to the *remote* host? Is the client code you show a proper [mcve]? Can it be used directly without editing to replicate the problem?

Comment: One end of Ethernet cable is connected to target board where server is running. The other end of same Ethernet cable is connected to host machine(x86). That means the server isn't running on remote host na. Client which is running on host machine is trying to connect to server which is running on target board(arm64)

Comment: So the server program *is* running? Then (one last time) have you changed the line `servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");` in the client program?

Comment: The code can be used directly to replicate the problem.

Comment: I'm trying by removing the line "servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");"

Comment: Don't remove it, change the IP-address to the the one of the remote system where the server is running. You *do* know what that line does? What the address `127.0.0.1` means? If there's any doubt, then please take a few steps back and read more about basic network programming.

Comment: "127.0.0.1" this means localhost na. servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); this can handle with any IP address na. Issue remains same even after setting target board IP.

Comment: after changing servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr to target board IP address, it's working. Thank you so much Some programmer dude